Tuple has no attribute 'colliderect'?
So I am making a game for a school assessment where a turtle has to get to the water. Previously, I was playtesting the game as the turtle being a rectangle. But now I want the turtle to actually be a turtle do I incorporated an image I made. I used get_rect(), but it now says Tuple has no attribute 'colliderect'. What can I do? Here is my current code (relevant parts of it):
#cross the sea
import pygame

pygame.init()

#set screen
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
SCREEN_WIDTH = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#sprite dimensions
goal_boundary1 = pygame.Rect((275, 200, 50, 50))
goal_boundary2 = pygame.Rect((275, 100, 50, 50))
goal_boundary3 = pygame.Rect((325, 150, 50, 50))
goal_boundary4 = pygame.Rect((225, 150, 50, 50))
goal = pygame.Rect((275, 150, 50, 50))
player = pygame.image.load('turtle1.png')
screen.blit(player, (275, 650))
wall1 = pygame.Rect((-25, 300, 400, 50))
wall2 = pygame.Rect((225, 500, 400, 50))
left_boundary = pygame.Rect((-50, 0, 50, 800))
right_boundary = pygame.Rect((600, 0, 50, 800))
top_boundary = pygame.Rect((0, -50, 600, 50))
bottom_boundary = pygame.Rect((0, 800, 600, 50))
player_rect = pygame.Surface.get_rect(player)
player_rect = (275, 650)
run = True
while run:
    
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), wall1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), wall2)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), left_boundary)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), right_boundary)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), top_boundary)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), bottom_boundary)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), goal)


    #controls
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_a] == True:
        player_rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
    elif key[pygame.K_d] == True:
        player_rect.move_ip(1, 0)
    elif key[pygame.K_s] == True:
        player_rect.move_ip(0, 1)   
    elif key[pygame.K_w] == True:
        player_rect.move_ip(0, -1) 
    
    #wall collisions
    if player_rect.colliderect(wall1):
        if key[pygame.K_a] == True:
            player_rect.move_ip(10, 0)
        elif key[pygame.K_d] == True:
            player_rect.move_ip(-10, 0)
        elif key[pygame.K_s] == True:
            player_rect.move_ip(0, -10)
        elif key[pygame.K_w] == True:
            player_rect.move_ip(0, 10) 

I expected to have full capability of the player the same as the rectangle, but I am met with this error.

The issue with your code is in the line:
player_rect = (275, 650)

You assigning player_rect with a tuple type, this is overwriting the recangle object that returned by get_rect(), tuple doesn't have an attribute called colliderect while recangle has.
To resolve this, you'll want to use player_rect.topleft to set the position of player_rect instead of overwriting it.
For example you can change the line code to:
player_rect = player.get_rect(topleft=(275, 650))  # Initial position

The player object is the same player from the line:
player = pygame.image.load('turtle1.png')

